# MigraDoc table formatting / cell indent

Tags: c#, printing, rtf, migradoc

I'm trying to create a table with MigraDoc. I want it to look like this:
[This is how the table should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frmjG.png)

Instead I'm only getting this:
[This is the table I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LajDt.png)

The text is too near to the border. The indent is missing. I tried

```
table.Format.LeftIndent = 0.2;
```

and

```
table.Format.LeftIndent = "0,2cm";
```

to set the indent for all table cells. But it didn't work. How can an indent for all table cells be achieved?

This is my complete test method:

```
private Document debugMigraDocTable()
{
  Document document = setupDocument();
  Section sectionProtocolHeader = document.AddSection();
  Paragraph measValueParagraph = sectionProtocolHeader.AddParagraph("Measurement");

  Table table = sectionProtocolHeader.AddTable();
  table.Format.LeftIndent = 0.8;

  // Table header      
  Column column = table.AddColumn("1,2cm");
  column = table.AddColumn("1,7cm");
  column = table.AddColumn("1,7cm");

  column = table.AddColumn("1,2cm");
  column = table.AddColumn("1,7cm");
  column = table.AddColumn("1,7cm");

  Row row = table.AddRow();
  row.HeadingFormat = true;
  row.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
  row.Format.Font.Bold = true;

  row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Key");
  row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("Value 1");
  row.Cells[2].AddParagraph("Value 2");
  row.Cells[3].AddParagraph("Key");
  row.Cells[4].AddParagraph("Value 1");
  row.Cells[5].AddParagraph("Value 2");

  // Table data
  row = table.AddRow();
  row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("1");
  row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("1,13");
  row.Cells[2].AddParagraph("");
  row.Cells[3].AddParagraph("33");
  row.Cells[4].AddParagraph("0,84");
  row.Cells[5].AddParagraph("");

  row = table.AddRow();
  row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("2");
  row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("1,19");
  row.Cells[2].AddParagraph("");
  row.Cells[3].AddParagraph("34");
  row.Cells[4].AddParagraph("1,35");
  row.Cells[5].AddParagraph("");

  row = table.AddRow();
  row.Cells[0].AddParagraph("3");
  row.Cells[1].AddParagraph("1,01");
  row.Cells[2].AddParagraph("");
  row.Cells[3].AddParagraph("35");
  row.Cells[4].AddParagraph("1,28");
  row.Cells[5].AddParagraph("");

  return document;
}
```

For preview and printing I render this to RTF:

```
  Document document = debugMigraDocTable();

  RtfDocumentRenderer rtfRenderer = new RtfDocumentRenderer();
  string rtf = rtfRenderer.RenderToString(document, Path.GetTempPath());
```

Comment: If you use 0.4 instead of 0.2 is it closer to what you want? What about 2 instead? 5? 10?

Comment: I've tried bigger values, "2" and "2cm". Nothing changed, it just looks the same.

Comment: Did you try the specific suggestions I made (without the quotes)?

Comment: Yes I've tried them all, and without quotes. Sadly nothing changes. As if the LeftIndent is overwritten somewhere.

Comment: Did you try setting it up as a `Watch` and see if something else is changing it?

Comment: I can't setup a Watch because when in the Watch window the Debugger is stating "The name 'LeftIndent' does not exist in the current context". But nonetheless with mouse over LeftIndent I see that it *is* existing.

Comment: Do you get what you want when creating PDF? RTF should look the same as PDF - but it could be a bug of the RTF renderer.

Comment: With the PdfDocumentRenderer the output was fine as it should be. Thank you!

Comment: So there is a bug in the RTF renderer. Indentation for RTF will work when this bug is fixed.